# How rows are handled in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question about what would cause the following error in bootstrap 3. 
Earlier I was writing some HTML and using CSS to style and was using bootstrap 3 for the rows and the columns.

Now I had everything inside of a fluid container and the container had margins etc. It has a standard header, and each row was split into two columns where each size has a width of 6 ie `col-lg-6 ....` inside of the container and then I had labels and inputs inside of my rows. Just a basic layout.

Now, whenever I tried to give a bottom border to each row I noticed that after inspecting the element the row was actually outside of the designated
columns / div.

However, when I changed the class from row to row-fluid it works perfectly. Why is this? Also, I noticed that if I make a clear-fix div after using row-fluid it fixes some apparent spacing issues, is this a requirement when using row-fluid or is my code just messed up somewhere.

Asking, because I thought row-fluid was only a bootstrap 2 and not a 3 thing, or am I mistaken?

I would include a fiddle showing you exactly what I'm talking about, but don't have the code available atm.

Comment: Really hard to diagnose without any sense of code. It's likely some conflicting CSS or the way it's marked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWBS-2
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#global

TWBS-3
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

The `<div>` nested under your `<div class="row">` carry the attributes container width dependent on viewport size, including all gutters and padding.

Comparing TWBS-2 and TWBS-3, TWBS-3's grid framework is designated as fluid for all viewport sizes. `.row-fluid` is not documented as an option, but I would refer to their version history for those specific changes. If the version history of the `<div class="row-fluid">` applies, then the gutters and padding of its children's `<div>` columns becomes full-width to the size of the container rather than fixed-width as designated by the rules of the TWB-S3 grid system without `.row-fluid` designation.

Comment: Okay, now that makes more sense. Thank you, now I understand where that issue is coming from